# Synonymize/merge [zipfile] with [zip]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The two tags refer to exactly the same thing - ZIP files.

I believe that [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) should be the main one, and [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile) should be a synonym. Comparison:

| tag | wiki | watchers | questions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) | > ZIP is a format for compressed file archives, allowing packaging of multiple files and directories into a single file. | 112 | 9.1k |
| [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile) | > For issues relating to creating and/or utilizing zip files. | 12 | 1.8k |

It is clear that they both refer to the same thing and the numbers show that `zip` should be the main.

From questions tagged [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile):

- 424 questions (about 23%) are also tagged with [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) already.
- 856 questions (about 47%) are also tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) which might be because of the Python package with the same name. But for that there is already [python-zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-zipfile).

Comment: Interesting. I would have expected these results from [su], but on [so], I would have expected [tag:zip] to refer to the [*Convolution operation*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)#In_programming_languages), which in almost all programming languages (except the Lisp family) is called `zip`.

Comment: This seems like a no-brainer; the only suggestion I would make is to consider whether something like `zip-compression` or `zip-format` would be a less ambiguous tag name than `zip`, given there will be the odd question misusing the tag for the `zip` function in Python or similar (as @JörgWMittag notes, this is a different meaning of the same word).

Comment: Going over the questions of [tag:zip] from the past 2 months I only found 5 questions that are actually about the `zip` function and not the format. I think this is fine and can be handled as any other tag mis-use and doesn't require a name change. The way I see it, `zip` is usually a *solution* to a problem so if the asker knew about it they wouldn't need to ask in the first place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have merged [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile) into [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) and here's my justification. There were over 1800 questions tagged zipfile when I started. Half of them were tagged Python. Out of that, less than half of them were asking about the usage of the Python ZipFile module. I retagged couple hundred questions to [python-zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-zipfile). What remained were generic questions asking about zip files.

54% of questions were tagged [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile) and [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip). 37% were tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Given how ambiguously the tag was used, it had no reason to exist on its own. Questions should either be tagged with [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) or [python-zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-zipfile).